# Stop the Android browser gets refreshed

Tags: android, html, browser

The Android browser gets refreshed within my app when the keyboard (Android version devices which have a flip keyboard) is pulled out and the app loses cetain elements. How can we prevent the browser to be refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the phone is flipped out, the active activity is closed and reopened. You need to use [OnSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) to persist your data and restore it when this happens.

UPDATE: You can also take a look at this thread for more info: [How to stop android activity destruction](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/61af733cf7cb6287/991547ead8fbe9f2?lnk=gst&q=How%20to%20stop%20android%20activity%20destruction%20#991547ead8fbe9f2)

Comment: Kindly provide me a simple example on the OnSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.